# ASP.NET Transfer data from controller action

Tags: asp.net-core

There is a sales service implemented as a Telegram bot. I need to create a website control panel for this service. Since the service is a .NET application I am thinking to use ASP.NET Core technology.

How do I transfer data from the controller action to the Program class containing all the functionality of the service (maybe it is worth defining the Program as a static class)?

Answer (score 1):

You may have misunderstood `Asp.Net Core`. `.net core` adopts the pipeline mode, that is, when you call the action in the controller, it will enter the middleware pipeline of `Program.cs`(.net 5 is `Startup.cs`), and execute in sequence according to the order of your middleware, adopting the principle of first in, last out. This means that if you follow the normal `.net core` logic, the value you get in the controller (except the parameters defined in the URL), you cannot pass it into `Program.cs`. When you successfully enter the action of the controller, `Program.cs` has been executed.

Not sure what your sales service looks like, but I think you can register it as a service and use it in your controllers using [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Helpful link: [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: As is usually done in such situations, when you need to implement a control panel for some services? Wouldn't it still be a better solution to implement REST API and interact with the service through it?

Comment: What's mean about `implement a control panel for some services`? Do you want to use ASP.NET panel controls? This is not supported in Core. If you want to call related services through Api, you can inject the service into the controller to call, and then return the corresponding View.

Comment: This is not a question about ASP.NET. The service is implemented as .NET application. It seems to me that the best solution would be to implement REST API and through it the frontend (a website, not necessarily ASP.NET Core App) will interact with the service. Is not it?